# Is it safe to use JavaScript with IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Everytime I think about using JavaScript (or any JS library) I see this red light in front of me. My only concern as usual is IE. So here is what I want to know:

1) Is JavaScript disabled by default in IE8 or IE9?

2) What about you, do you feel safe when including a JavaScript code in a site that may be viewed using IE 8 or 9?

3) I found so many problems when applying CSS rules to html5 tags in IE8 so I used Modernizr. However it depends on JavaScript to enable html5 tags so I could apply CSS rules to them in IE. Am I risking to lose CSS styling as well, by using Modernizr?

Comment: 1. No. 2. It's safe, some things just aren't supported. 3. Repeat 2.

Comment: JavaScript work fine in IE8 + 9. IE8 have some bugs and you need to patch your code especially for IE.

Answer (score 1):

1. No JavaScript is not disabled by default in IE8/IE9
2. Yes I feel safe, because I code defensively with those browsers in mind if they're mentioned as requirements in the project spec.
3. Again, code for your requirements.  If you have a *real* reason to believe that modernizr isn't going to cover your requirements, don't use it and style accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1) No, it is enabled by default

2) Safety is not a concern for you in that case. Nowadays, modern Javscript libraries even support IE quite well. They often implement workarounds for features not supported by IE, so that users just can't use all features the libraries has, but the scripts shouldn't crash any more.
That said, you still need to test your sites in IE.

Javascript has become a widely accepted standard finally.